# yii2 two form in a single page

Tags: php, yii2

Hi all i have two form in a single page 1st work but when i submit 2nd form then no data submit from 2nd form and re submit first form data. Actually my form is wizard base and use jquery.steps.js for wizard.

I want to submit first form at step 2 and 2nd form at step 4.
My first form like this

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin( [
        'id' => 'form1_step1', 'options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']      
    ]); ?>
/*...*/
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

after some line of html code 2nd form start

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin( [
        'id' => 'form2_step2'      
    ]); ?>
/*...*/
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Have any body any solutions?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you got solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use a javascript based form wizard to have only 1 form, or keep the values from the first form in the second one (or in the session). When you submit a form you just submit one of them, not both in the same time.